# How to get list of files with a specific extension in a given folder?

Tags: c++, filesystems, file-management

I want to get the file names of all files that have a specific extension in a given folder (and recursively, its subfolders).  That is, the file name (and extension), not the full file path.  This is incredibly simple in languages like Python, but I'm not familiar with the constructs for this in C++.   How can it be done?

Comment: [`boost::filesystem`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) is good with files.

Comment: Writing C++ after Python must feel like writing in an assembly language after C++ :) As far as the standard C++ is concerned, this is a surprisingly code-intensive task. I second the suggestion of using `boost::filesystem`.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_VERSION 3
#define BOOST_FILESYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED 
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

/**
 * \brief   Return the filenames of all files that have the specified extension
 *          in the specified directory and all subdirectories.
 */
std::vector<fs::path> get_all(fs::path const & root, std::string const & ext)
{
    std::vector<fs::path> paths;

    if (fs::exists(root) && fs::is_directory(root))
    {
        for (auto const & entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(root))
        {
            if (fs::is_regular_file(entry) && entry.path().extension() == ext)
                paths.emplace_back(entry.path().filename());
        }
    }

    return paths;
}
```

Comment: there, this is the portable answer.

Comment: The only thing that didn't work for me is the 'and', I replaced it by '&&'. The rest is excellent. +1

Comment: Note: for the extension don't forget to add a dot...for example ".jpg" is the correct, not "jpg".

Comment: @Jav_Rock You're likely using VS and have to include <iso646.h> to get non-symbol logical operators.

Comment: the code is `using namespace std;` (should add that)

Comment: @Jav_Rock and is a pre-processor macro, at least gcc implemented it. FYI

Comment: Also note that this code only provides the filenames (i.e. without the full path to the file).  Should you desire the full path, remove the `.filename()` call.  Otherwise, this code works great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 58):

a C++17 code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string path("/your/dir/");
    std::string ext(".sample");
    for (auto &p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(path))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ext)
            std::cout << p.path().stem().string() << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm surprised this was below the other non-cross-platform, non-STL solutions! The only other improvements that could be made are using `std::endl` or making 'p' a `const` variable.

Comment: @RaleighL. `std::endl` is a risky pessimisation since it's in a loop. \n is more correct by default

Answer (score 19):

On windows you do something like this:

```
void listFiles( const char* path )
{
   struct _finddata_t dirFile;
   long hFile;

   if (( hFile = _findfirst( path, &dirFile )) != -1 )
   {
      do
      {
         if ( !strcmp( dirFile.name, "."   )) continue;
         if ( !strcmp( dirFile.name, ".."  )) continue;
         if ( gIgnoreHidden )
         {
            if ( dirFile.attrib & _A_HIDDEN ) continue;
            if ( dirFile.name[0] == '.' ) continue;
         }

         // dirFile.name is the name of the file. Do whatever string comparison 
         // you want here. Something like:
         if ( strstr( dirFile.name, ".txt" ))
            printf( "found a .txt file: %s", dirFile.name );

      } while ( _findnext( hFile, &dirFile ) == 0 );
      _findclose( hFile );
   }
}
```

On Posix, like Linux or OsX:

```
void listFiles( const char* path )
{
   DIR* dirFile = opendir( path );
   if ( dirFile ) 
   {
      struct dirent* hFile;
      errno = 0;
      while (( hFile = readdir( dirFile )) != NULL ) 
      {
         if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, "."  )) continue;
         if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, ".." )) continue;

         // in linux hidden files all start with '.'
         if ( gIgnoreHidden && ( hFile->d_name[0] == '.' )) continue;

         // dirFile.name is the name of the file. Do whatever string comparison 
         // you want here. Something like:
         if ( strstr( hFile->d_name, ".txt" ))
            printf( "found an .txt file: %s", hFile->d_name );
      } 
      closedir( dirFile );
   }
}
```

Comment: Your solutions would find the file in the pattern, "foo.txt.exe".  I wouldn't consider that to have a .txt extension.

Comment: On windows, where are you setting the value of "gIgnoreHidden". Is it a flag?

Comment: yes - its a global boolean in the example. But really you can do anything here - like pass it in as another argument to listFiles.

Comment: On x64 builds from Windows 8 (?) onwards, I believe the hFile should be an intptr_t rather than a long. Using long will result in badness when _findnext is called.

Comment: For Posix, what are the includes needed for opendir, readdir, and closedir?

Answer (score 5):

Get list of files and process each file and loop through them and store back in different folder

```
void getFilesList(string filePath,string extension, vector<string> & returnFileName)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileInfo;
    HANDLE hFind;   
    string  fullPath = filePath + extension;
    hFind = FindFirstFile(fullPath.c_str(), &fileInfo);
    if (hFind != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        returnFileName.push_back(filePath+fileInfo.cFileName);
        while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fileInfo) != 0){
            returnFileName.push_back(filePath+fileInfo.cFileName);
        }
    }
}
```

USE: you can use like this load all the files from folder and loop through one by one

```
String optfileName ="";        
String inputFolderPath =""; 
String extension = "*.jpg*";
getFilesList(inputFolderPath,extension,filesPaths);
vector<string>::const_iterator it = filesPaths.begin();
while( it != filesPaths.end())
{
    frame = imread(*it);//read file names
        //doyourwork here ( frame );
    sprintf(buf, "%s/Out/%d.jpg", optfileName.c_str(),it->c_str());
    imwrite(buf,frame);   
    it++;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to return a const vector & from getFIlesList?  
filesPaths's declaration was missed in your usage example.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what OS you are on, but there are several options.

As commenters have mentioned, [boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) will work if you can use boost.

Other options are

- [CFileFind Class with MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f33e1618%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)
- [FindFirstFile/FindNextFile with WIN32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [opendir/readdir with POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirent.h).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution (works on *nix systems):

```
#include <dirent.h>

bool FindAllFiles(std::string path, std::string type, std::vector<std::string> &FileList){
  DIR *dir;
  struct dirent *ent;
  FileList.clear();

  if ((dir = opendir (path.c_str())) != NULL) {
    //Examine all files in this directory
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
      std::string filename = std::string(ent->d_name);
      if(filename.length() > 4){
        std::string ext = filename.substr(filename.size() - 3);
        if(ext == type){
          //store this file if it's correct type
          FileList.push_back(filename);
        }
      }
    }
    closedir (dir);
  } else {
    //Couldn't open dir
    std::cerr << "Could not open directory: " << path << "\n";
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Obviously change the desired extension to whatever you like. Also assumes a 3 character type.