# How to read specific file names of a directory into an array

Tags: c++

I tried to read all file names of a directory into array and my code successfully addes whole file names into array. However, what i need it to do,

1st one is getting ,not all of them, only spesific file names which end like .cpp or .java. It should be done in this part and my comparisons did not work. How can i do that ?

```
DIR           *dir;
struct dirent *dirEntry;
vector<string> dirlist;  

while ((dirEntry = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
            {
                   //here
                       dirlist.push_back(dirEntry->d_name);
            }
```

2dn one is getting the directory location from user. I couldn't do that also, it only works if i write the location adress, how can i get location from user to get files ?

```
dir = opendir(//here);
```

Comment: what are the types, what comparison did not work?

Comment: Which OS are you programming for? This is platform dependent.

Comment: Sorry about that i didnt post it. the dirlist type is vector<string>. And working on windows is enough for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would work for your case,

```
DIR* dirFile = opendir( path );
if ( dirFile ) 
{
   struct dirent* hFile;
   errno = 0;
   while (( hFile = readdir( dirFile )) != NULL )
   {
      if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, "."  )) continue;
      if ( !strcmp( hFile->d_name, ".." )) continue;
      // in linux hidden files all start with '.'
      if ( gIgnoreHidden && ( hFile->d_name[0] == '.' )) continue;

      // dirFile.name is the name of the file. Do whatever string comparison 
      // you want here. Something like:
      if ( strstr( hFile->d_name, ".txt" ))
          printf( "found an .txt file: %s", hFile->d_name );
   } 
   closedir( dirFile );
}
```

Ref: [How to get list of files with a specific extension in a given folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140483/how-to-get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-extension-in-a-given-folder)

Comment: Thanx man, i was looking for strstr( hFile->d_name, ".txt" ) this part :D

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/filesystem.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  path p (argv[1]);

  directory_iterator end_itr;

  std::vector<std::string> fileNames;
  std::vector<std::string> dirNames;


  for (directory_iterator itr(p); itr != end_itr; ++itr)
  {
    if (is_regular_file(itr->path()))
    {
      string file = itr->path().string();
      cout << "file = " << file << endl;
      fileNames.push_back(file);
    }
    else if (is_directory(itr->path()))
    {
      string dir = itr->path().string();
      cout << "directory = " << dir << endl;
      dirNames.push_back(dir);
    }
  }
}
```