# Getting specfic files in C++ code from *nix system

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I want to get all the files of type `A*.txt` present in current directory via C++ code. My OS is *Nix system. Also, I want to get the names of such files.

Please suggest how can this be done.

I tried using system command but system doesn't return anything apart a integer which says if command was executed properly or not.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get list of files with a specific extension in a given folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140483/how-to-get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-extension-in-a-given-folder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically three ways you can go about this.

One is to use basically what you tried before, but using the [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) function, which allows you to read the output of the command(s) you run.

The second solution is to use e.g. [`opendir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) and [`readdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) or [`scandir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) to manually filter and find the files you look for.

The third and easiest way is to use the [`glob`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html) function.

---

There is actually a fourth way as well, one which is platform independent and more C++-ish than the above methods: Using [the Boost filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).