# Waiting for a file to be created

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to write a method to monitor a directory for a file to be created. This file will have the extension `.complete`. If it is not there, I want to wait for it to appear. When it does appear, I want to find extract the name of the file before the extension, delete the `.complete` file, do some processing, and then go back to listening for a new `.complete` file.

Here's what I have so far. I think I just need help extracting the name of the file, assuming I did the wildcard's correctly.

```
while(1) {
    if (!boost::filesystem::exists("/var/test/*.complete")) {
        cout << ".complete file does not exist" << endl;
    }
    else {

        //extract name of .complete file minus extension
        //do my processing
        system("rm *.complete");
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `boost::filesystem::exists` performs wildcard expansion. Are you sure that it does?

Comment: it seems like it doesn't without some extra steps

Comment: boost filesystem library is able to iterate regular files under specified path. it is also able to give the extension of one regular file.

Comment: That would make much more sense. And then, you have the filename already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

I used the get_all function from this answer below and added that to my program
[How to get list of files with a specific extension in a given folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140483/how-to-get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-extension-in-a-given-folder)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to boost, but in a few easy step you can get what you want

Step 1 : Read the directory (readdir or equivalent)

Step 2 : You'll get all files included in the directory as a const char *

Step 3 : Get std::string instead of const char *

Step 4 : fileName.find(".complete")

you get it :)