# Searching for files with specific extension - using recursive_directory_iterator - <filesystem> library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am trying to search for files with certain extensions in a directory, using the "recursive_directory_iterator" function inside  library.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2017.

I am following the code in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47975458/4145697

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
void get_list_of_files(void)
{
    std::string constructed_path_str_dbg = "C:\\Cpp_trials\\Trials\\Debug\\baseline\\cpp_files_trial";
    std::string ext(".sample");
    for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(constructed_path_str_after))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ext())  // errors E0980 and C2064
            std::cout << p << '\n';         // errors E0349 and C2679
    }
}
```

But I am having the following compilation errors:

```
E0980   call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type 

E0349   no operator "<<" matches these operands 

C2064   term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments 

C2679   binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::filesystem::directory_entry' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the code you provided, I tested and modified it.

1. Change `constructed_path_str_after` to `constructed_path_str_dbg`
2. Change `ext()` to `ext`

The following are my test results：

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <experimental/filesystem>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

int main()
{
    std::string constructed_path_str_dbg = "C:\\Cpp_trials\\Trials\\Debug\\baseline\\cpp_files_trial";
    std::string ext(".txt");
    for (auto& p : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(constructed_path_str_dbg))
    {
        if (p.path().extension() == ext)  
            std::cout << p << '\n';        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

I hope to know why you would use constructed_path_str_after, because this is related to your problem solving. I can only speculate on your needs based on the existing code.

Comment: Thank you Barrnet, I fixed the error you mentioned, and I changed ext() to ext, and the error in this line was removed. But I am still having errors in the line ---> std::cout << p << '\n';  (errors E0349 and C2679)

Comment: However, when I tested it on my VS, C2679 did not appear. And I did not find the content of `const std::filesystem::directory_entry` in your code. I think you could provide more relevant information or code. I suggest you try to set the `C++17 standard` in `Properties->C/C++->C++ Language Standard`.